# Draw image grid in python

Tags: python, grid

i have this exercise in school, make a function that draws a grid in an existing image. draw_grid(img, s, c)
img - image
s - spacing of lines
c - color

```
    def draw_grid(img, s, c):
        a = s
        b = s
        for i in range(len(img)):
            for j in range(len(img[0])):
                if i == a:
                    img[i][j] = c
            if img[i][j] == c:
                a = a + s
        for i in range(len(img)):
            for j in img[i]:
                if img[i].index(j) == b:
                    img[i][img[i].index(j)] = c
                    b = b + s
        im.visd(img)
    import image as im
    img = im.create(200, 100, (200,200,200))
```

With the code i have it just generates the horizontal lines.

[this is what i`ve got so far:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAH9x.jpg)

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is not a valid problem description. And is im a library ? If so, add the tag for it.

Comment: im is the image library, i just added it. and i hope the new description is ok. I`m kind of new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with `if img[i].index(j) == b:`, index return the index of the first occurrence of its argument in the list, but j should already be an index, and not an element that you're looking for in your image.

Your loops seems too complicated, you don't need a, b or any 'if', if you use range with 3 arguments, the third argument is the step for increment :

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i) # print 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
```

So you can have loops like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(img), s):
    for j in range(len(img[0])):
        img[i][j] = c
for i in range(0, len(img[0]), s):
    for j in range(len(img)):
        img[j][i] = c
```

Comment: Ty! u r amazing sir. ive been working on this for 2 days now and i can`t belive it never ocurred to me that range() can be used like this. Ty again.